# display ckEditor uploaded image in PRAWN PDF

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ckeditor, carrierwave, prawn

Gems I use in my app are Prawn, Cloudinary, Carrierwave and ckEditor.

I use Cloudinary to store images. With the help of Carrierwave I upload images to Cloudinary while using ckEditor(WYSIWYG).

Below is a full ckEditor uploader.
ckeditor_picture_uploader.rb

```
class CkeditorPictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
include Ckeditor::Backend::CarrierWave
include Cloudinary::CarrierWave
include CarrierWave::MiniMagick


[:extract_content_type, :set_size, :read_dimensions].each do |method|
 define_method :"#{method}_with_cloudinary" do
 send(:"#{method}_without_cloudinary") if self.file.is_a?(CarrierWave::SanitizedFile)
 {}
end
 alias_method_chain method, :cloudinary
end

process :read_dimensions

# Create different versions of your uploaded files:
version :thumb do
  process :resize_to_fill => [118, 100]
end

version :content do
  process :resize_to_limit => [800, 800]
end

# Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
# For images you might use something like this:
 def extension_white_list
  Ckeditor.image_file_types
 end
end
```

In Publication(place I use ckEditor) controller show action I specify parameter for Prawn to use:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.pdf do
    pdf = PublicationPdf.new(@publication)
    send_data pdf.render, filename: "#{@publication.title}.pdf",
                          type: "application/pdf",
                          disposition: "inline"
```

I use separate file on specifying dimension to generate PrawnPDF. publication_pdf.rb:

```
  class PublicationPdf < Prawn::Document

  require "open-uri"

def initialize(publication)
    super(top_margin: 50)
    @publication = publication
    ckeditor_pic
end

def ckeditor_pic 
    image open("http://res.cloudinary.com/long_path/f29d54371fa9d7_development.jpg")
end
  end
```

In ckeditor_pic method I just give direct path to Cloudinary to see if Prawn would generate PDF with an image and it does. Now I would like to give generic path for Prawn to generate PDF's with pictures fetched from Cloudinary.

Issue for me is to give this generic path. How to show Prawn that he must fetch images from Cloudinary for specific Publication record?

Comment: As a caution, please don't use comments to ask others to answer your question. These were being flagged all over the site, and I've removed them.

Comment: The URL for an image is `@publication.image.url`, but you clearly already know that. Can you simplify the question somehow? You're asking about three different gems, but the question isn't related to all of them, is it? What exactly isn't working the way you expected it to? What is the task you can't figure out how to solve?

Comment: See changes in question. I started to use Cloudinary. In general issue remains the same - Prawn to generate PDF with pictures that were added via ckEditor(exactly would be via Carrierwave) to Cloudinary.